# {closure}() must be an instance of Faker\Generator\Generator on laravel factory seed

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-seeding

when I use
php artisan db:seed
I got the error?
In **UserFactory.php line 27:**

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::{closure}() must be an instance
of Faker\Generator\Generator, instance of Faker\Generator given
```

`Userfactory.php`
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

(this is line 27)

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Admin::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

        return [
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
            'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
            'remember_token' => str_random(10),
        ];
    });
```

AdminsTableSeeder.php

```
public function run()
{
    factory('App\Models\Admin',3)->create([
        'password' => bcrypt('123456')
        ]);
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
public function run()
{
    // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(AdminsTableSeeder::class);
}
```

I don't know how it happens.

Comment: It should be like this 
$factory->define(App\Admin::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

Comment: reload your tinker and try again.

Comment: @SachinAghera I don't know what are you meaning? the difference is?

Comment: @AnowarHossain I don't use the tinker and how do I reload it? I try restart the computer is got the same error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

```
(this is line 27)
    $factory->define(App\Models\Admin::class, function (Faker $faker)
```

That means that instead of using `function(Faker\Generator $faker)` in your function, instead use `function (Faker $faker)`

That solved it for me.

Comment: Does it work the same in Controllers. I want to create some fakers in Controller.